# How to get Android device token for push notifications?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have been through various Stackoverflow questions and answers, and looked through documentation and articles but all the approaches we've tried such as FireBaseInstanceId and extending the FirebaseMessagingService all result in an empty token.

It is not clear how we get the token for the user's device, for push notification purposes.

Could someone please clarify how in 2021 we can get the user's device token?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

FireBaseInstanceId was deprecated and [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId) say to use FirebaseMessaging for retrieve FCM token.
In particular the method [getToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging#public-taskstring-gettoken) works in this way:

```
Returns the FCM registration token for this Firebase project. This creates a Firebase Installations ID, if one does not exist
```

So, in order to generate token, I don't think is mandatory to extends FirebaseMessagingService, just call it like so wherever you want

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener {
        if (!it.isSuccessful) {
            return@addOnCompleteListener
        }
        val token = it.result //this is the token retrieved
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work and is one of the approaches we've already tried. The token always comes back null, even on the first install and run.

Comment: This method worked fine for me.  I was able to get the token from task.result.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have a sample push notification project working, then the Java code is:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
          if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
            return;
          }

          // Get new FCM registration token
          String token = task.getResult();

          // Log and toast
          String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
          Log.d(TAG, msg);
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Source= https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        Log.e("newToken", token);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }

}
```

Add this in Android manifest file:

```
<service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Whenever your Application is installed first time and open, MyFirebaseMessagingService created and onNewToken(String token) method called and token generated which is your Device Token or FCM Token.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work and is one of the approaches we've already tried. The token always comes back null, even on the first install and run.

Comment: Please try uninstalling the application and then install it again and make sure you have the latest google-services.json from your project console.

Answer (score -1):

from this way you can get the unique device id

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.
                TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

`getDeviceId()` will returns the unique device ID.

```
String deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

By the way this needs permission of `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`

Comment: We've just tried this. There is a warning that READ_PHONE_STATE is reserved only for system apps. When running the app with this ignored it causes the app to crash at startup.